# Converting a string using the Double.TryParse method in C#

Tags: c#, string, double

Right now, I converted all 3 strings into an int, but I'm having trouble converting each string using the Double.TryParse method. I want to use that method instead of int.

I tried using this type of code if (Double.TryParse(value, out number)), but I'm not to sure exactly if this is right.

```
//Ask the user for height
Console.Write("Please enter the first part of your height in feet:");
string _height = Console.ReadLine();
int _heightVal = Int32.Parse(_height);

//Ask the user for inches
Console.Write("Please enter the second part of your height in inches:");
string _inches = Console.ReadLine();
int _inchesVal = Int32.Parse(_inches);

//Ask the user for pounds
Console.Write("Please enter your weight in pounds:");
string _pounds = Console.ReadLine();
int _poundsVal = Int32.Parse(_pounds);
```

Comment: I don't see where you;re using `Double.TryParse`.

Comment: `tryparse` should be wrapped in an `if` where you somehow deal with the failure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: `Double` seems like a bad choice for feet and inches. Maybe for weight, but if it is fractional perhaps use decimal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
double heightVal = 0;
double.TryParse(_height, out heightVal);
```

heightVal will have the value of the Parse from `_height` if Parsing is successful, otherwise it will have the it's previous value (0 in here)

`TryParse()` returns a boolean indicating if the Parsing was successful that you can use it like:

```
bool success = double.TryParse(_height, out heightVal);
```

or

```
if(double.TryParse(_height, out heightVal))
{
     //Parse was successful and heightVal contains the new value
     // and you can use it in here
}
```

Fail Example:

```
double defaultValue = 0;
string str = "abc"
bool success = double.TryParse(str, defaultValue );
```

> **Output:**
>
> defaultValue = 0
>
> success = false

Success Example:

```
double defaultValue = 0;
string str = "123"
bool success = double.TryParse(str, defaultValue );
```

> **Output:**
>
> defaultValue = 123
>
> success = true

Comment: Might want to add an example that utilizes the returned boolean.

Comment: @JonathonChase I'm doing it ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think you just trying to force use enter the correct value
you can use wile loop
like this

```
 double userHeight = 0.0;
        while (true)
        { 
            //Ask the user for height
            Console.Write("Please enter the first part of your height in feet:");
            string _height = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Double.TryParse(_height, out double height))
            {
                userHeight = height;
                break;
            }

        }
```

then apply to all your questions